# Overcoming python server MaxRequestWorkers on ubuntu apache

Tags: python, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have a python server running on apache (Ubuntu 18.04) that receives continuous POST requests from client as a loop for gathering data on the server side and send back a response every one second till reaching the MaxRequestWorkers. Then the process stops..

Is there any way (or codes; in python) to let the process endless by clearing caches, freeing RAMs or any way?

Comment: Can you fix the client?

Comment: Fixing the client? How?

Comment: It only needs to open one connection!

Comment: You mean one connection/request from client side & running a loop on the server?